# Realm throws errors in build files, won't compile

Tags: android-studio, realm

It was all working well yesterday. This morning I updated support repositories for `recyclerView` and `android studio` made me update something with the emulator, and now every time I try to launch the app in emulator or rebuild my app, it throws these errors, along with others like them:

```
    Error:(27, 8) error: FiringScheduleRealmProxy is not abstract and does not override abstract method realmGet$proxyState() in RealmObjectProxy

    Error:(62, 29) error: cannot find symbol variable realm

    Error:(63, 55) error: cannot find symbol variable row

    Error:(23, 1) error: DefaultRealmModuleMediator is not abstract and does not override abstract method <E>createDetachedCopy(E,int,Map<RealmModel,CacheData<RealmModel>>) in RealmProxyMediator
    where E is a type-variable:
    E extends RealmModel declared in method <E>createDetachedCopy(E,int,Map<RealmModel,CacheData<RealmModel>>)

    Error:(99, 46) error: getModelClasses() in DefaultRealmModuleMediator cannot override getModelClasses() in RealmProxyMediator
    return type Set<Class<? extends RealmObject>> is not compatible with Set<Class<? extends RealmModel>>

    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    > Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Here is the app build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "fautt.kilncontroller"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets', 'src/main/assets/fonts'] } }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.3.0'

}
```

and the project build.gradle:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:0.88.2"
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Just do a clean/rebuild.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my question. Did both clean and rebuild, but I get the same errors still.

Comment: Try to delete your build folder

Comment: In this case it's also a question whether you use `realm android-adapters`, and if you've updated it yet. Also your Realm version is also important. But I still think this is just something that needs `clean` and it'd be done.

Comment: I added the  compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.3.0' line to gradle this morning as well, but haven't actually used either the recyclerView or real android-adapter yet. I'll update my question with both my gradle files to give hopefully relevant info. I did the clean by going to build>clean. is there some other way to do it?

Comment: @ChristianMelchior you mean literally just right click on app>build and delete the whole thing? that sounds like a scary thing to do.

Comment: Yes. It is fine. `app/build` only contain files created by the build system, so deleting them is completely safe.

Comment: @ChristianMelchior just did it and did a rebuild, got same errors.

Comment: Your `appcompat` and `recyclerview` versions are mismatched, also you're using an extremely outdated version of Realm (it's at 1.1.0 and you're using 0.88.2), and make sure you disable `Instant Run`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce that fixed the errors. Out of curiosity, why should I disable Instant Run?

Comment: Instant Run causes issues with annotation processing.